# Update library versions in virtualenv Python

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv on a remote Linux machine. I have the Python 2.6.7 version, and I've put in the requirements.txt file all the libraries and their versions that my application needs :

```
    argcomplete==1.0.0                                  
    docutils==0.12                                      
    jsonschema==2.4.0                            
    mysql-python==1.2.3      
    numpy==1.6.1
    scipy==0.17.0                      
    scikit-learn==0.17.1
```

In the remote machine, NumPy is already installed (1.5.1 version). But my application requires a version >=1.6.1 (since it uses Scikit-learn library).

Somehow in the virtualenv, it won't install this version and it just keeps the 1.5.1 one that's already installed on the machine (knew this using a pip freeze).

I can't update the version that's installed on the remote machine,

so is there any way to force the update of the version of the NumPy library in the virtualenv ONLY ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create virtualenv with flag `--no-site-packages` like this:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
```

Comment: tried it but no success. Actually, I used this command and tried to pip freeze the new virtualenv, and even though I don't have a requirements.txt or installed any package, there is a list of libraries already installed (including numpy 1.5.1)

Comment: Have you tried to update your virtualenv ? `sudo pip install -U virtualenv`

Comment: Yes i just did, no progress either. I believe it is intentional that whenever someone creates a virtualenv on this remote machine, there are already some pre-installed packages with specified versions.

What I don't understand is why I cannot update, nor uninstall a package inside my own virtualenv :(